# PHP how to Submit information from two drop-down lists

Tags: php, html

Apologies if this question has already been asked, but I've been unable to find the answer.

I'm attempting to submit results from 2 dropdown lists to another page, `example.php`. I know how to do this with two separate forms however then obviously only one piece of drop down information is transferred:

```
<form method=get action="example.php">
Pick a student: <select name="name">
<?php
$NAMES = array('David','Francis','Jakob','McKenzie','Patrick','Shomo','Weizheng');
$LOCATIONS = array('LAX', 'JFK', 'DAL', 'LGA');
foreach($NAMES as $v){
  echo "<option>" . $v . "</option>";
}
print "</form>";
?>

//Getting the second drop down list
<form method=get action="example.php">
<input type=submit value="submit">
Pick a Flight: <select name="name">
<?php
foreach($LOCATIONS as $v){
  echo "<option>" . $v . "</option>";
}
?>
<input type=submit value="submit">
</form>
```

How Can I have a single "submit" button which transfers the selection of both the `$NAMES` and `$LOCATIONS` arrays to `example.php`?

Comment: put them into wo different `<select>`s (different name), but within the same form - and use `</select>` after adding all options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the two select elements in **the same form** (i.e. remove `print "</form>";` and the second `<form method=get action="example.php">`) and (since you are using PHP) either give them *different names* or a name that ends in `[]` (therefore making the value a PHP array when it's submitted).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to use the value selected from two drop down (city_name and flight) in next page(example.php)

```
<form method="GET" action="example.php">
Pick a student: 
<select name="city_name">
<?php
$names = array('David','Francis','Jakob','McKenzie','Patrick','Shomo','Weizheng');
$locations = array('LAX', 'JFK', 'DAL', 'LGA');
foreach($names as $v){
  echo "<option>" . $v . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>

Pick a Flight: 
<select name="flight">
<?php
foreach($locations as $v){
  echo "<option>" . $v . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<input type=submit value="submit">
</form>
```

example.php

```
<?php
echo 'The City Name is :'.$_GET['city_name'];
echo 'The Flight is :'.$_GET['flight'];
?>
```

Comment: You should warn the OP about the XSS security problem you introduced or better, not introduce one at all.